# Loading application.properties file to java.util.Properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I read through the Spring Boot documentation for [externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and I see that it automatically loads the src/main/resources/application.properties file which can be then wired to the bean properties using annotation.

However I want to have a generic `PropertyHelper` class which can be used to build the `java.util.Properties` with the properties in application.properties. Can this be done?

We are currently achieving this manually as below:

```
public class PropertyHelper {

    private static Properties loadProperties() {
        try {

             String propsName = "application.properties";
             InputStream propsStream = PropertyHelper.class
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propsName);
            if (propsStream == null) {
                throw new IOException("Could not read config properties");
            }

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(propsStream);
```

Comment: add a slash before `application.properties`

Comment: Or you can just autowire Environment which is a Properties-type bean containing all values from the file

Comment: With `Environment` you _can_ get the properties, but it doesn't have a list of all properties. you only can use `env.getProperty("propertyName")` to get the property

Comment: For **Can this be done ?** , what is the result of your experiment?

Comment: However, the `Environment` is very likely a `ConfigurableEnvironment`, which allows you to iterate the property sources, and you *can* iterate the properties of any `PropertySource` that is an `EnumerablePropertySource`. --- The advantage of using `Environment` is that you gain support for features like Profiles and YAML. But the question is: Why do you need to iterate them? Don't you know the names of the properties that are of interest to you?

Comment: I think u can use component on top of the class and add property field environment with autowired ,create on the configuration with bean annotation this way you can use general class to handle property file everywhere (just an idea)

Comment: Don't do this, you'll be breaking the configuration layer abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Wrapper` around Environment, which would return a ready-to-use `PropertySource`:

You would use it this way:

```
@PropertySource(name="myName", value="classpath:/myName.properties")
public class YourService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomMapProperties customMapProperties;
    ...
    MapPropertySource mapPropertySource = customMapProperties.getMapProperties("myName");
    for(String key: mapPropertySource.getSource().keySet()){
        System.out.println(mapPropertySource.getProperty(key));
    }
```

`CustomMapProperties` is injected with `Environment` and returns the request & loaded property file based on its name:

```
@Component
public class CustomMapProperties {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public MapPropertySource getMapProperties(String name) {
        for (Iterator<?> it = ((AbstractEnvironment) env).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Object propertySource = it.next();
            if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource
                    && ((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getName().equals(name)) {
                return (MapPropertySource) propertySource;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I derive a Properties object from Spring's Environment. I look for property sources of type java.util.Properties, which in my case will give me system properties and application properties.

```
@Resource
private Environment environment;


@Bean
public Properties properties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    for (PropertySource<?> source : ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources()) {
        if (source.getSource() instanceof Properties) {
            log.info("Loading properties from property source " + source.getName());
            Properties props = (Properties) source.getSource();
            properties.putAll(props);
        }
    }

    return properties;
}
```

Note however that the order may be significant; you would probably want to load the system properties after other properties, so they can override application properties. In that case, add some more control code using  `source.getName()` to pick out "systemProperties":

```
@Bean
public Properties properties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    Properties systemProperties = null;

    for (PropertySource<?> source : ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources()) {
        if (source.getSource() instanceof Properties) {
            if ("systemProperties".equalsIgnoreCase(source.getName())) {
                log.info("Found system properties from property source " + source.getName());
                systemProperties = (Properties) source.getSource();
            } else {
                log.info("Loading properties from property source " + source.getName());
                Properties props = (Properties) source.getSource();
                properties.putAll(props);
            }
        }
    }

    // Load this at the end so they can override application properties.
    if (systemProperties != null) {
        log.info("Loading system properties from property source.");
        properties.putAll(systemProperties);
    }

    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject application context arguments in constructor and relay it into java.util.properties:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;

public MyComponentClass(ApplicationArguments arguments) {

  Properties properties = getProperties(arguments);
}

private static Properties getProperties(ApplicationArguments arguments) {

  Properties properties = new Properties();

  for (String argementName : arguments.getOptionNames()) {

    List<String> argumentValues = arguments.getOptionValues(argementName);

    if (argumentValues.size() > 0) {
      properties.put(argementName, argumentValues.get(0));
    }
  }

  return properties;
}
```